# How to export react hook from one file to another, and vice versa?

Tags: react-hooks

I'm new in React and have a small problem.

I've got two files - FileA n' FileB.
Both have button and simple hook counter. How to export [countA, setCountA] to file B and vice versa?

I want to have something like this:

ButtonAClicked: setCountA(countA + 1), setCountB(countB - 1)

ButtonBClicked: setCountB(countB + 1), setCountA(countA - 1)

Any idea???

Comment: we can't export only useState values , can be done this by declaring parent state which will control both the A and B counters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If say below is your Main.js file:

```
const[a,setA]=useState(0);
const[b,setB]=useState(0);

const updateA=(value:number)=>{
setA(value);
}

const updateB=(value:number)=>{
setB(value);
}

<AFile a={a} b={b} updateA={updateA} updateB={updateB}/>
<BFile a={a} b={b} updateA={updateA} updateB={updateB}/>
```

Inside A file:

```
function A({a,b,updateA,updateB}) {
const onClickA=()=>{
updateA(a+1);
updateB(b-1);
}
<Button onClick={onClickA}/>
}
```

Similarily you can have your B file.

Comment: it's not what I expected.... so maybe that's the reason why I didn't know the solution LOL